# How to access cookies from ApplicationController (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I want to access cookies and then perform the same operation regardless of the action or controller.

I don't want to write out a method that gets called from each of my myriad action methods because, aside from being a pain, it doesn't make for very agile code.  I'd rather make the call to my cookie-handling method from the ApplicationController class (the superclass for all the controller classes) in application_controller.rb.

However, calling `cookies()` in the body of the ApplicationController class raises an 'undefined method' error.  (I guess that `cookies` doesn't get defined until later.)

What can I do?  Should I overwrite the `initialize()` method of the ApplicationController and call my cookie-handling method from there?  If so, how should I pass the arguments to the super constructor?

P.S. I'm using Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :handle_cookies
  def handle_cookies
    # Do whatever it is you want to do with your cookies
  end
end
```

The `before_filter` method will call whatever subroutine you indicate (`:handle_cookies`) after `cookies` has been compiled into a hash.  Adding this code to your application controller will mean that all the other controllers inherit it and will perform the same function.

Answer (score 27):

It's a hash, not a method:

```
cookies[:some_key]
```

... instead of:

```
cookies(:some_key)
```

Comment: Thanks.  But isn't it actually a method that returns a hash? `cookies[:key]` is really shorthand for `cookies()[:key]`?  Regardless, can you help me find a solution?  Calling `cookies` and expecting a hash doesn't avoid the error I was getting before.

Comment: It's a method that returns a CookieJar object (which inherits from Hash). What exactly are you trying to do that you need to access the method and not the cookie data?

Comment: I am after the cookie data.  The problem is how to access it without calling it from each action.  (How can I access it from the superclass, for example, without calling it from a method within a controller?)

Comment: This is right answer. I have set a cookie using js-cookie and able to do cookies[:some_key] on rails controller and that works right. Thank yo

Answer (score 0):

I am using rails 5 and below code worked for me.

```
cookies[:key_name]
```

Comment: this is not javascript or java, this is Ruby. Brackets are not needed, `cookies[:key_name]`