# Blocking public access to my website with Coming-Soon page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, blocking

I have a Rails website and it is live under root url. I want to block public access to it. Preferably with a Coming Soon page. But I still want to access it "maybe with a login, or any other way" so that I can deploy my codes, continue adding content until I'm ready for public release.

Comment: Merry Christmas, though I am a Chinese. You may need an authorization gem named cancancan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, merry Xmas to you too.

As for your question there are a lot of various solution here.
You could do it directly through your HTTP Server, for exemple, tell you server to automaticaly redirect to /coming_soon if a defined HTTP HEADER is not found in the request.

You could also set a custom cookie value in you browser with a randomized string and check the value in a before_filter 
(see [How to access cookies from ApplicationController (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281685/how-to-access-cookies-from-applicationcontroller-rails) )

Or use an authorization gem like cancancan or pundit (I do prefer the latter over the former but it's more a matter of taste) to define your redirection rules (I do think it would be overkill to use these gem only for that behavior though)

Comment: Wow thanks mate! Many options  I’m going to research these directions deeper as I have no idea how to do any of them now 