# Admin template, avoid open sidebar on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have installed sufee admin dashboard on my rails project. Template page is [here](https://github.com/puikinsh/sufee-admin-dashboard). Demo is [here](https://colorlib.com/polygon/sufee/)

It works fine as in the demo.

This is the code for toggle:

```
$('#menuToggle').on('click', function(event) {
    $('body').toggleClass('open');
});
```

You can notice that when navigating to new page the sidebar opens, even if it was collapsed. I would like it instead to persist the collapsed state. And same for open state, if it's open and I navigate to new page it should stay open. In other words sidebar state should change only when clicking the toggle. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#menuToggle').off('click').on('click', function(event) {
  $('body').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: This has the exact same behaviour I am having with original code.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the site and seeing its behaviour, you have to add class="open" to the body tag, and that's all

Comment: This makes the exact opposite. If sidebar is open and page reloads the sidebar gets closed. While it should stay open. In other words the state open or close should persist on new page.

Answer (score 0):

If the default state of your sidebar is open, then on any non-dynamic page load, it will be open. You'll need to introduce some sort of persistent data storage to store the current state for the current user.

The most common choice here would be to set the cookie on the same click event. To prevent the sidebar from collapsing after the page has loaded, you could read the cookie server-side to determine whether to include the `open` body class or not to help prevent [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)-type issues.

Something like this should get you started:

```
function setCookie(name, value){
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + 31536000000);

    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}

var getCookie = function(name){
    var pair = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name + '=([^;]+)'));
    return !!pair ? pair[1] : null;
};

$('#menuToggle').on('click', function(){
    if( $('body').hasClass('open'){
        // Menu Open: Collapse it, save Collapsed State
        $('body').removeClass('open');
        setCookie('menuState', 'collapsed');
    } else {
        // Menu Collapsed: Open it and save Open State
        $('body').addClass('open');
        setCookie('menuState', 'open');
    }
});
```

Now if you need to read that cookie state in JS you can do something like the following (though this can lead to the FOUC I mentioned before, so you may want to [read the cookie serverside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281685/how-to-access-cookies-from-applicationcontroller-rails) - I'm unfamiliar with how to do that in Rails but it seems easy enough

```
var menuState = getCookie('menuState');
if( menuState == 'collapsed' ){
    $('body').removeClass('open');
} else if( menuState == 'open' ){
    $('body').addClass('open');
}
```

Comment: I'mnot really good at javascript so I'm gonna need a while to understand this. I thought there was a simpler solution.. Btw with this code as it is the toggle does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this approach. just to get the idea, by the way the error on the snippet is [normal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets), so better try it on a separate file first. you'll see it when you reload your browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#menuToggle').click(function(){
     
     if($('body').hasClass('open')){
       sessionStorage.removeItem('body');
     }else{
       sessionStorage.setItem('body', 'open');
     }
     
   });
  
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('body')){
    $('body').addClass('open');
  }else{
    $('body').removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.sidebar{
  width: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  height: 200px;
}
body.open .sidebar{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="menuToggle">Toggle</button>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The behaviour with this is that when a new page is loaded the sidebar opens and suddenly gets closed by itself

Comment: have you tried it on your code or on a separate file?